# React table class not sorting strings as numbers first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

A generic class for tables called GenericTable has been made as a react component using react-table as a base:

```
import React from 'react'
import { translate } from '../../Translations'
import { toId } from '../../../utility/common'
import { useTable, useSortBy, usePagination, useFilters, useGlobalFilter } from 'react-table'

function Table({ id, tableConfig, columns, data, fileName, currPage, filterValue, sortArray, onPageChange, onFilterChange, onSortChange, noDataText }) {
  const filterTypes = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      fuzzyText: filterRows,
      text: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
        return rows.filter((row) => {
          const rowValue = row.values[id]
          return rowValue !== undefined ? String(rowValue).toLowerCase().startsWith(String(filterValue).toLowerCase()) : true
        })
      },
    }),
    []
  )

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize, globalFilter, sortBy },
    visibleColumns,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setGlobalFilter,
    rows,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: {
        pageIndex: currPage,
        pageSize: tableConfig.initialPageSize || 10,
        globalFilter: filterValue,
        sortBy: sortArray,
      },
      filterTypes,
    },
    useFilters,
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  )

  onPageChange = onPageChange.bind(this)
  onFilterChange = onFilterChange.bind(this)
  onSortChange = onSortChange.bind(this)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    onSortChange(sortBy)
  }, [sortBy])

  let paginationArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
  if (tableConfig.initialPageSize && !paginationArray.includes(tableConfig.initialPageSize)) {
    paginationArray.push(tableConfig.initialPageSize)
    paginationArray.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a - b
    })
  }

  let scrollableClasses = tableConfig.scroll ? ' custom-scrollbar border-bottom' : ''
  let scrollHeightClass = tableConfig.scroll ? { maxHeight: tableConfig.scrollHeight } : {}

  return (
    <div>
      <table id={id + '-header'} className='text-center table table-striped table-sm rt-table' {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead className='rt-head'>
          <tr>
            <th style={{ border: 'none' }} colSpan={visibleColumns.length}>
              <div className='align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between'>
                <div className={tableConfig.showFilter ? '' : ' d-none'}>
                  <GlobalFilter preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows} globalFilter={globalFilter} setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter} onFilterChange={onFilterChange} />
                </div>
                <div className={tableConfig.showExport ? '' : ' d-none'}>
                  <CSVLink data={data} className='btn btn-block text-center' id={id + '-csv-export-button'} filename={fileName + '.csv'}>
                    {translate('generate_report')}
                  </CSVLink>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          {createHeader(headerGroups)}
        </thead>
      </table>
      <div className={'rt-body' + scrollableClasses} style={scrollHeightClass}>
        <table id={id} className='text-center table table-striped table-sm'>
          <tbody className={tableConfig.scroll ? '' : 'border-bottom'} {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {createRows(id, page, prepareRow, visibleColumns, noDataText)}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div id={'pagination-bar'} className={'align-items-center justify-content-between' + (tableConfig.showPagination ? ' d-flex' : ' d-none')}>
        <div className='d-flex'>
          <select
            className='rt-paginate-page-selector'
            value={pageSize}
            onChange={(e) => {
              gotoPage(0)
              onPageChange(0)
              setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
            }}
          >
            {paginationArray.map((pageSize) => (
              <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                {pageSize}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <div>
            {translate('showing')} {1 + pageIndex * pageSize} {translate('to').toLowerCase()} {(pageIndex + 1) * pageSize < rows.length ? (pageIndex + 1) * pageSize : rows.length}{' '}
            {translate('of')}
            {' ' + rows.length} {translate('entries')}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='d-flex'>
          <button
            className='page-link rounded-left rt-paginate-button'
            onClick={() => {
              gotoPage(0)
              onPageChange(0)
            }}
            disabled={!canPreviousPage}
          >
            {'First'}
          </button>{' '}
          <button
            className='page-link rt-paginate-button'
            onClick={() => {
              previousPage()
              onPageChange(pageIndex - 1)
            }}
            disabled={!canPreviousPage}
          >
            {'Previous'}
          </button>{' '}
          <button
            className='page-link rt-paginate-button'
            onClick={() => {
              nextPage()
              onPageChange(pageIndex + 1)
            }}
            disabled={!canNextPage}
          >
            {'Next'}
          </button>{' '}
          <button
            className='page-link rounded-right rt-paginate-button'
            onClick={() => {
              gotoPage(pageCount - 1)
              onPageChange(pageCount - 1)
            }}
            disabled={!canNextPage}
          >
            {'Last'}
          </button>{' '}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export class GenericTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    const { id, tableConfig, columns, data, fileName, page, filter, sort, onPageChange, onFilterChange, onSortChange, noDataText } = this.props

    return (
      <Table
        id={id}
        tableConfig={tableConfig}
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        fileName={fileName}
        currPage={page}
        filterValue={filter}
        sortArray={sort}
        onPageChange={onPageChange}
        onFilterChange={onFilterChange}
        onSortChange={onSortChange}
        noDataText={noDataText}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

The problem is that the tables that have rows that start with letters and another with numbers are not sorted correctly.

The rows that start with numbers are sorted after the rows that start with letters.

```
export class OperationalHistoryTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      table_filter: '',
      table_page: 0,
      table_sort: [
        {
          id: 'event_time',
          desc: true,
        },
      ],
    }
  }

  render() {
    var columns = [
      {
        header: translate('event_time'),
        accessor: 'event_time',
        width: '15%',
        Cell: (row) => {
          return filteredTime(row.cell.value)
        },
      },
      {
        header: translate('event_type'),
        accessor: 'event_type',
        width: '40%',
      },
      {
        header: translate('additional_info'),
        accessor: 'additional_info',
        width: '45%',
      },
    ]

    const tableConfig = {
      showFilter: true,
      showExport: true,
      showPagination: true,
      autoResetPage: false,
    }

    return (
      <GenericTable
        id='operational-history-table'
        tableConfig={tableConfig}
        columns={columns}
        data={this.eventHistoryData()}
        fileName='Operational History'
        page={this.state.table_page}
        filter={this.state.table_filter}
        sort={this.state.table_sort}
        onPageChange={(pageValue) => {
          this.setState({ table_page: pageValue })
        }}
        onFilterChange={(filter) => {
          this.setState({
            table_filter: filter,
            table_page: 0,
          })
        }}
        onSortChange={(sortBy) => {
          this.setState({ table_sort: sortBy })
        }}
        noDataText={translate('no_events')}
      />
    )
  }
```

I attach an image describing the problem. When I click on sorting rows by an ascending column the rows that start with numbers are placed at the end.

However, rows with only letters are ordered correctly, that is, for example, a row that begins with the letter "a" goes before a row that begins with the letter "b".

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a sample photo that includes the following rows: 1, 2, 3, a, b, c?

Comment: Yes I have changed the image in the question but I also add you the link: https://imgur.com/a/Ipvu4n2

Comment: Thank you! It illustrates the error much better, I am already looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `useSortBy` hook sorts text values before numbers. To achieve the expected behavior of sorting numbers first, you'll need to override the default sorting rules.

You need to override the `sortType` basic value with your own rule.

#### sortType parameters

> sortType: String | Function(rowA: , rowB: , columnId: String, desc: Bool)

The `sortType` requires three parameters: the two rows to be compared and the identifier of the column to be taken into consideration.

#### Example

**Declare custom sort function**

```js
const {
  // ...
} = useTable(
  {
    columns,
    data,
    initialState: {
      // ...
    },
    filterTypes,

    // Here --------
    sortTypes: {
      custom: (rowA, rowB, columnId) => {
        const a = rowA.values[columnId];
        const b = rowB.values[columnId];
        
        if (!isNaN(Number(a)) && !isNaN(Number(b))) {
          return Number(a) - Number(b);
        }
        return a.localeCompare(b);
      }
    },
    // -------------

  },
  useFilters,
  useGlobalFilter,
  useSortBy,
  usePagination
)
```

**Use your sort function on your column**

```js
columns: [
  {
    Header: "Column #1",
    accessor: "column_1",
    sortType: "custom" // here
  },
  {
    Header: "Column #2",
    accessor: "column_2",
    sortType: "custom" // here
  }
]
```

Comment: It seems a valid solution, but it does not work, the rows are sorted as same

Comment: You are right, I modified the sorting function! I wanted to be fast... but it came at the expense of quality. I'm sorry!